# GRAPH OF percentages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I want create a definite structure. It's  a percentage chart.

This is my objective, I want to get this:

[image]

I try with this code

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1.0, 0.6, 0.4}
\definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0.29, 0.59, 0.82}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolor}{
{fill=color1!80, draw=color1},
{fill=color2!80, draw=color2},
{fill=color3!80, draw=color3},
{fill=color4!80, draw=color4},
}

\pgfplotsset{
discard if/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
        \fi
    }
},
discard if not/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
        \else
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
        \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{filecontents*}{coefficienti.dat}
T       K       Q       Kf      n
400     0.0463  32.9        5.78        0.321
500     0.124   24.8        6.30        0.275
600     0.115   24.6        6.30        0.261
700     1.64        24.4        11.9        0.151
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    ymin=0,
    ybar=0, bar width=20, bar shift=0,
    xtick={data},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    cycle list name=mycolor,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style = {
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=3
    }]

% first complete plot to place the x-axis labels
\addplot+ table[x=T,y=K] {coefficienti.dat};
% the bars with different colors
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{500,600,700}{        
  \addplot+[discard if not={T}{#1}] table[x=T,y=K] {coefficienti.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But in that base I can't writte text.

Someone can help me to create my percentage chart.

Any idea?

thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, but the question is a bit unclear to me. Where do you want to have what? You mean you want to show the `nodes near coords` with percentage values`?

Comment: I want to get the graph of the first image [visa, mastercard etc]. Any idea? thank you very much

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

It is simplest if you add the labels to the data file itself. Then you "only" need to change your code "a bit" so you get the desired result.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    % added `xlables' column
    \begin{filecontents*}{coefficienti.dat}
        T       K       Q       Kf      n       xlables
        400     0.0463  32.9    5.78    0.321   {VISA}
        500     0.124   24.8    6.30    0.275   {MasterCard}
        600     0.115   24.6    6.30    0.261   {American \\ Express}
        700     1.64    24.4    11.9    0.151   {Union Pay \\ (China)}
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
    \definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
    \definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1.0, 0.6, 0.4}
    \definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0.29, 0.59, 0.82}

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolor}{
        {fill=color1!80, draw=color1},
        {fill=color2!80, draw=color2},
        {fill=color3!80, draw=color3},
        {fill=color4!80, draw=color4},
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % changed definition of this style (so it works with `\coordindex')
        discard if not/.style 2 args={
            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
            filter discard warning=false,
            x filter/.expression={
                #1 == #2 ? #1 : NaN
            },
        },
    }
    % load the table (because it is needed over and over again)
    \pgfplotstableread{coefficienti.dat}\loadedtable
    % store number of rows in table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NoOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,
        ybar=0,
        bar width=20,
        bar shift=0,
        % changing `xtick' to this avoids the need for the dummy `\addplot'
        xtick={0,...,\NoOfRows},
        % then you can use a table column to show the `xticklabels'
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{xlables},
        % added so `xticklabels' allow linebreaks
        x tick label style={
            align=center,
        },
        ymajorgrids=true,
        cycle list name=mycolor,
        % added value part of the key to be able to show the values as percentages
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        every node near coord/.append style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=2,
        },
        % adapt the axis line style
        separate axis lines,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=none,
    ]

        % adapted
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\NoOfRows}{
            \addplot+ [
                discard if not={\coordindex}{#1},
            ] table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y=K,
            ] {\loadedtable};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: is possible remove the black line rectangle? Sorry but  it produce error in my texmaker :(

Comment: Sure. See my edited answer.

Comment: nice!!! it's perfect thank you so much!! last thing, it possible to convert this graph in a image with standalone?? Now, i can't compilate the code :/

Comment: I would guess so. But I am the wrong person to ask that, because I never do this. If I want to export the images I use PGFPlots `external` library (see [tag:tikz-external]). I think you mean that you cannot *compile* the code anymore, right? What error message to you get?

Comment: my error is about  PGFPlots library. Can't compile the package. I think is better create an other design

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't help. *Which* library? If you think it's worth you can ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117).

Comment: why you don't put all code, like `\usepackage`?

Comment: I have provided a full working minimal example including `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` ...

Comment: mmmmm yes, is true. Texmaker tell me: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'xlables' from table 'coefficienti.dat'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases).. ]. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, if the file `coefficienti.dat` already exists it will not be overwritten. Thus, delete it manually before TeXing and it will work. Good luck.

Comment: where I can delete it? In miktex data?

Comment: With the explorer in the directory wherever you have stored your TeX file containing the code from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the text on the axis lables with `xticklabels={Visa,Mastercard, American Express, Union Pay, JCB}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1.0, 0.6, 0.4}
\definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0.29, 0.59, 0.82}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolor}{
{fill=color1!80, draw=color1},
{fill=color2!80, draw=color2},
{fill=color3!80, draw=color3},
{fill=color4!80, draw=color4},
}

\pgfplotsset{
discard if/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
        \fi
    }
},
discard if not/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
        \else
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
        \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{filecontents*}{coefficienti.dat}
T       K       Q       Kf      n
400     0.0463  32.9        5.78        0.321
500     0.124   24.8        6.30        0.275
600     0.115   24.6        6.30        0.261
700     1.64        24.4        11.9        0.151
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    ymin=0,
    ybar=0, bar width=20, bar shift=0,
    xtick={data},
    xticklabels={Visa,Mastercard, American Express, Union Pay, JCB},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=east},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    cycle list name=mycolor,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style = {
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=3
    }]

% first complete plot to place the x-axis labels
\addplot+ table[x=T,y=K] {coefficienti.dat};
% the bars with different colors
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{500,600,700}{        
  \addplot+[discard if not={T}{#1}] table[x=T,y=K] {coefficienti.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]